# Buscando Array de variáveis via Ajax e inserindo em seus devidos inputs de um form

Tags: ajax, array

tenho um formulário que busca e preenche, via ajax, o nome da pessoa e ano de nascimento (em seus respectivos campos), tudo isso a partir do cpf digitado pelo usuário.

É algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Digite o CPF do usuário ______________  <button>BUSCAR DADOS</button>

NOME _________________________

DATA DE NSACIMENTO __________________
```

Com isso, é feito duas requisições da seguinte forma:

```
$('#botao').click(function(){

        //BUSCA NOME
        $.get('buscar_nome.php?cpf='+$('#cpf').val(), 

        function(result) {
        $('#nome').val(result);
        });

        //BUSCA DATA DE NASCIMENTO
        $.get('buscar_data_nascimento.php?cpf='+$('#cpf').val(), 

        function(result) {
        $('#datanascimento').val(result);
        });
```

As páginas PHP são com a seguinte lógica:

buscar_nome.php

```
$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];
$sq1 = select * from tabela where cpf = '$cpf';
$registro = myslq_fetch_array($sq1);

echo registro['nome'];
```

buscar_data_nascimento.php

```
$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];
$sq1 = select * from tabela where cpf = '$cpf';
$registro = myslq_fetch_array($sq1);

echo registro['datanascimento'];
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém, gostaria de otimizar a busca desses dados (nome e data de nascimento) usando apenas uma requisição. Imagino que devo usar Array. Como devo proceder?

Comment: você pode usar um objeto JSON tb cara, é interessante pela praticidade, o mesmo possui "indices" com nome assim fica mais fácil o acesso na minha concepção.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo assim.

busca.php

```
$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];
$sq1 = select nome,datanascimento from tabela where cpf = '$cpf';
$registro = myslq_fetch_array($sq1);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($registro);
```

E no javascript acessar da seguinte maneira

```
$.get('buscar.php?cpf='+$('#cpf').val(), 

function(result) {
   $('#nome').val(result.nome);
   $('#datanascimento').val(result.datanascimento);
});
```

Só tome cuidado com esse trecho

> where cpf = '$cpf'

É possível fazer um sql injection nesse parâmetro. Você deve sanitizar e validar os parâmetros que vêm do usuário antes de coloca-lo em um select dessa maneira.

Comment: Olá Vinicius, deu certo. Obgd pela ajuda. Vou fazer as validações. =D

Comment: @Luis, se a resposta te ajudou e vc quiser marcar como resposta eu agradeço =).